# Why printing the array of strings does print first characters only?

Tags: c++, c-strings

Please explain the difference in the output of two programs.

`cout << branch[i]` in first program gives output as:

```
Architecture
Electrical
Computer
Civil
```

`cout << *branch[i]` in second program gives output as:

```
A
E
C
C
```

Why?

What is the logic behind `*branch[i]` giving only first character of each word as output and `branch[i]` giving full string as an output?

Program 1

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *branch[4] = { "Architecture", "Electrical", "Computer", "Civil" };

    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) 
        cout << branch[i] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Program 2

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *branch[4] = { "Architecture", "Electrical", "Computer", "Civil" };

    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) 
        cout << *branch[i] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not a homework problem statement. It is a doubt, I encountered while reading the ppt slides

Comment: `*branch[i]` is the same as `branch[i][0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a `const char*` with assignment operator, for example:

```
const char* some_string = "some text inside";
```

What actually happens is the text being stored in the special, read-only memory **with added the null terminating char after it (`'\0'`)**. It happens the same when declaring an array of `const char*`s. Every single `const char*` in your array points **to the first character of the text in the memory**.

To understand what happens next, you need to understand how does `std::cout <<` work with `const char*`s. While `const char*` is a pointer, it can point to only on thing at a time - to the beginning of your text. What `std::cout <<` does with it, is it prints every single character, including the one that is being pointed by mentioned pointer *until the null terminating character is encountered*. Thus, if you declare:

```
const char* s = "text";
std::cout << s;
```

Your computer will allocate read-only memory and assign bytes to hold `"text\0"` and make your `s` point to the very first character (being `'t'`).

So far so good, but why does calling `std::cout << *s` output only a single character? That is because you *dereference* the pointer, getting what it points to - a single character.

I encourage you to read about pointer semantics and dereferencing a pointer. You'll then understand this very easily.

**If, by any chance, you cannot connect what you have just read here to your example:**

Declaring `const char* branch[4];` you declare an array of `const char*`s. Calling `branch[0]` is replaced by `*(branch + 0)`, which is derefecencing your array, which results in receiving a single `const char*`. Then, if you do `*branch[0]` it is being understood as `*(*(branch + 0))`, which is **dereferencing a `const char*`** resulting in receiving a single character.

Answer (score 1):

`branch[i]` contains a `char*` pointer, which is pointing to the first `char` of a null-terminated string.

`*branch[i]` is using `operator*` to dereference that pointer to access that first `char`.

`operator<<` is overloaded to accept both `char` and `char*` inputs.  In the first overload, it prints a single character.  In the second overload, it outputs characters in consecutive memory until it reaches a null character.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [operators precedences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Subscript operator `[]` has a higher precedence than an indirection operator `*`.

So `branch[i]` returns `const char *` and `*branch[i]` returns `const char`.

Answer (score -1):

`*branch[i]` prints a single `char` located at the address pointed to by `branch[i]`.

`branch[i]` prints the whole `char*` array starting with the address pointed to by `branch[i]`.

Comment: Ok. But then why *branch[i] prints only the first character. If *branch[i] prints character,shouldn't branch[i] print address ?

Comment: Because branch[i] is an address of a `char`.